# Writing help information for user defined functions in R

Tags: r, function

I frequently use user defined functions in my code.
RStudio supports the automatic completion of code using the Tab key. I find this amazing because I always can read quickly what is supposed to go in the (...) of functions/calls.

However, my user defined functions just show the parameters, no additional info and obviously, no help page.
This isn't so much pain for me but I would like to share code I think it would be useful to have some information at hand besides the #coments in every line.

Nowadays, when I share, my lines usually look like this

```
myfun <- function(x1,x2,x3,...){

# This is a function for this and that

# x1 is a factor, x2 is an integer ...
# This line of code is useful for transformation of x2 by x1
  some code here
# Now we do this other thing
  more code
# This is where the magic happens
  return (magic)
}
```

I think this line by line comment is great but I'd like to improve it and make some things handy just like every other function.

Comment: Put your functions in a package and document them.

Comment: I guess this isn't a coding question then? should I delete it and look for writing a package?

Comment: Actually I think it might be a coding question but it is at the moment too vague to know. If your hope was for a popup of a full or reduced help page from the console line than that might be a bit difficult (and "too broad" because it would require serious extensions to the RStudio IDE), but if the questions was how to retain comments when a user-defined function is `source()`-ed, then that might be a do-able coding function.

Comment: I am afraid I was looking for the first, the popup of reduced help page :( ....For comments I read them directly from the script and people I work with do the same

Comment: @Matias Andina No I don't think there's anything wrong with the topic of your question; I'm just saying that a package is the most standard way of doing this. Incidentally, it's probably the easiest way of achieving this as well. What would the alternative be? Writing a custom parser, which, as 42- noted, would almost certainly require also developing an RStudio extension? That sounds like 1000x more effort, especially when packages like roxygen2, etc... make documentation generation relatively painless.

Comment: It is a great question! Looking forward to the answer which hopefully comes.

Comment: Intermediate suggestion: In the context of a "tab-completion" activity, I wonder if the IDE (say Rstudio or the MacGUI) could be modified slightly to allow a cmd-key or ctrl-key combination to execute: `help(<whatever-is-the-current-tabbed-display>)`?

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, but if you are interested in exploring this further, you should start at the `rcompgen`-help page (although that's not a function name) and also examine the code of:

```
rc.settings
```

Also, executing this allows you to see what the `.CompletionEnv` has in it for currently loaded packages:

```
names(rc.status())
#-----
 [1] "attached_packages" "comps"             "linebuffer"        "start"            
 [5] "options"           "help_topics"       "isFirstArg"        "fileName"         
 [9] "end"               "token"             "fguess"            "settings"
```

And if you just look at:

```
rc.status()$help_topics
```

... you see the character items that the tab-completion mechanism uses for matching. On my machine at the moment there are 8881 items in that vector.

Comment: rc.status()$help_topics gives character(0)

Comment: Very possible. When I use R launched from a Terminal window, there is no tab-completion and that is the result I get. When done from the MacGUI, which has tab-completion, those are the results I see.